# How do i use Zend Tool In Netbeans

Tags: php

How do i run Zend Tool in netbeans? I added it to the software but can't find the button to press to bring up the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Right-Click on you Project in the Project panel, Choose Zend->Run Command.

Make sure you have configured the Zend Tool in Tools->Options,PHP Tab, Zend Tab, then browse for your zf.bat file (if on Windows).